# Add a cool down period before AdMob rewarded video can be viewed again

Tags: android, admob, rewardedvideoad, admob-rewardedvideoad

The reward button will be disabled in this period to inform the user. Once the cool down ends, an ad will be loaded and button will become clickable. I plan to do this using [`Handler.postDelayed()` and shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64280509/keep-button-disabled-for-specified-interval-in-android-even-when-app-is-restart).

Can AdMob frequency capping provide a better solution? Can I find when the next ad will be available using the AdMob Android SDK?